# Exit remaining condition check, if one condition met - SQL/Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I have  condition to check from Orace DB as below.

```sql
select case when STATUS ='AP' THEN STUDENT_ID else null end AS approved_student,    
       case when STATUS ='DN' THEN STUDENT_ID else null end AS denied_student,  
       case when STATUS ='PE' THEN STUDENT_ID else null end as pending_student
```

One student can fall into `'AP'`, `'DN'`,`'PE'`. But if one student is approved, then do not count them in `PE` or `DN` OR do not go to the next condition check.

Also if that student is not approved, then code should check for Pending and denial conditions

meaning I need to exit/do not continue  the following check  if one id is present in bock 1.

How can I check this condition in SQL?

Comment: That's not how SQL works. You must evaluate/return every query column for every row, even if the value is null.

Comment: It's not clear what data you're starting with, or what results you want. Please add example data and desired results to make this into a [mre] as suggested here; [Why should I provide a Minimal Reproducible Example for a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/333952)

Answer (score 2):

> meaning I need to exit/do not continue the following check if one id is present in bock 1.

Assuming that you have a single row for each student then each student can only have a single value for `status` so it will be either `'AP'` or `'DN'` or `'PE'` and it is impossible for a row to have more than one of those values.

You do not need to change your code and do not need to try to exit the second `CASE` statement if the first passes; just let all the `CASE` expressions evaluate and if one passed then all the others will fail.

---

If a student can have multiple rows then use aggregation:

```sql
SELECT student_id,
       CASE
       WHEN COUNT(CASE status WHEN 'AP' THEN 1 END) > 0
       THEN 'AP'
       WHEN COUNT(CASE status WHEN 'DN' THEN 1 END) > 0
       THEN 'DN'
       WHEN COUNT(CASE status WHEN 'PE' THEN 1 END) > 0
       THEN 'PE'
       END AS status
FROM   table_name
GROUP BY student_id
```

Answer (score 1):

It is not clear what exactly you want to get. If we suppose that you have a table of students where each student has one of three statuses...

```sql
WITH      --  S a m p l e   D a t a :
    students (STUDENT_ID, STUDENT_NAME, STATUS) as
        ( Select 1, 'Mike', 'AP' From Dual Union All
          Select 2, 'John', 'DN' From Dual Union All
          Select 3, 'Jane', 'AP' From Dual Union All
          Select 4, 'Kate', 'PE' From Dual 
        )
```

... then your query from the question (slightly changed) would be like ...

```sql
Select  Case When STATUS = 'AP' Then STUDENT_ID End "APPROVED_STUDENT",  -- no need for "...Else Null..." - 
        Case When STATUS = 'DN' Then STUDENT_ID End "DENIED_STUDENT",
        Case When STATUS = 'PE' Then STUDENT_ID End "PENDING_STUDENT"
From   students
```

... with the result that doesn't look like something usefull

```sql
/*    R e s u l t :     (sql from question)
APPROVED_STUDENT DENIED_STUDENT PENDING_STUDENT
---------------- -------------- ---------------
               1                               
                              2                
               3                               
                                              4   */
```

Maybe you need something more informative like:
Option 1.

```sql
Select  STUDENT_ID, STUDENT_NAME, 
        Case When STATUS = 'AP' Then 'YES' Else 'NO' End "APPROVED_STUDENT",  
        Case When STATUS = 'DN' Then 'YES' Else 'NO' End "DENIED_STUDENT",
        Case When STATUS = 'PE' Then 'YES' Else 'NO' End "PENDING_STUDENT"
From   students
```

```sql
/*      R e s u l t :      (Option 1.)
STUDENT_ID STUDENT_NAME APPROVED_STUDENT DENIED_STUDENT PENDING_STUDENT
---------- ------------ ---------------- -------------- ---------------
         1 Mike         YES              NO             NO 
         2 John         NO               YES            NO 
         3 Jane         YES              NO             NO 
         4 Kate         NO               NO             YES           */
```

Option 2.

```sql
Select  Distinct
        LISTAGG(Case When STATUS = 'AP' Then STUDENT_NAME End, ', ') WITHIN GROUP (Order By STUDENT_NAME) Over() "APPROVED_LIST",   
        LISTAGG(Case When STATUS = 'DN' Then STUDENT_NAME End, ', ') WITHIN GROUP (Order By STUDENT_NAME) Over() "DENIED_LIST",
        LISTAGG(Case When STATUS = 'PE' Then STUDENT_NAME End, ', ') WITHIN GROUP (Order By STUDENT_NAME) Over() "PENDING_LIST"
From   students
```

```sql
/*      R e s u l t :     (Option 2.)
APPROVED_LIST    DENIED_LIST    PENDING_LIST
---------------- -------------- ---------------
Jane, Mike       John           Kate            */
```

Those are just two (three with your sql) different results for the most simple context where there is one student with one status. There are more options for this scenario, though. And if the context is more complex then you should realy explain it in detail: - what data you have, how they are connected and what you are expecting to get as a result.
**NOTE**:
CASE expression is sequential and the first condition that is true will get the coresponding value and exit CASE. So it is very important in which order you set up the conditions. In this simple scenario it is irrelevant but in most cases that is crucial.
Here is Option 3. that results with one additional column:

```sql
Select  STUDENT_ID, STUDENT_NAME, STATUS,
        Case When STATUS = 'AP' Then 'APPROVED'
             When STATUS = 'DN' Then 'DENIED'
             When STATUS = 'PE' Then 'PENDING' 
        End "STATUS_FULL"
From   students
```

```sql
/*      R e s u l t :      (Option 3.)
STUDENT_ID STUDENT_NAME STATUS STATUS_FULL
---------- ------------ ------ -----------
         1 Mike         AP     APPROVED
         2 John         DN     DENIED 
         3 Jane         AP     APPROVED
         4 Kate         PE     PENDING   */
```